# Java statements and instructions

Tags: java

I read that all Java statements end with a semicolon. But i've also noticed many times on the internet that

```
public static void main
```

has been called a statement although it doesn't have a semicolon. So, is there a definite term for statement? Is there any difference between statement and instruction in Java?

Comment: It's not a statement. It's an incomplete method declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that all Java statements end with a semicolon.

That is incorrect.  The following Java statements do NOT need to end with a semicolon:

- `if` statements
- some loop statements (`for`, `while`)
- `synchronized` statements
- `try` statements
- block statements; i.e. `{ ... }`

The thing that these all have in common is that they end in a subsidiary statement which may be either a block or not; e.g.

```
if (a) this.b();
```

versus

```
if (a) { this.b(); }
```

> But i've also noticed many times on the internet that `public static void main`
> has been called a statement although it doesn't have a semicolon.

That is not a statement.  It is a part of a declaration.  (A method declaration.)

> So, is there a definite term for statement?

The Java Language Specification says this:

> *"The sequence of execution of a program is controlled by statements, which are executed for their effect and do not have values."*

So from that we can extract the following loose definition: A statement is a Java language construct that is executable, is executed for its effect, and doesn't have a value<sup>1</sup>.

However, I think that a better way to see the difference between a statement and a non-statement in Java is to list the different kinds of statements.

- Start with the list above.
- Add the following:

  - local variable declarations (with or without initializers)
  - expression statements comprising:

    - calls to methods, method references and lambdas
    - `new` statements
    - assignment statements
    - prefix / postfix increment and decrement statements
  - `do` ... `while` statements.
  - `continue` and `break` statements
  - `throw` statements
  - `return` statements
  - empty statements; e.g. the second `;` in `a = b; ;`

Not-statements (declarations) include the following:

- A `class` declaration
- An `interface` declaration
- An `enum` declaration
- A field declaration
- A method declaration
- A constructor declaration
- A `package` declaration
- An `import` declaration
- A `module` declaration
- An initializer block
- Any expression that is not an expression statement.  (This depends in part on the syntactic context.)

(Some people call `package`, `import` and `module` declarations "statements", but that is not what the JLS calls them, and that doesn't fit the definition above.)

> Is there any difference between statement and instruction in Java?

The term "instruction" doesn't have any technical meaning in Java.  However, a Java statement is a form of instruction to the program to do something.

---

<sup>1 - The "doesn't have a value" is a bit of a stretch.  For example, a statement such a `i++;` does produce a value ... but we are ignoring it.  However, the above is a direct quotation from the JLS, albeit that it is descriptive rather than a serious attempt to define "statement".</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) has plenty of detail on statements, as well as examples. It summarises them as follows:

> The sequence of execution of a program is controlled by *statements*, which are executed for their effect and do not have values.

Statements are distinct from [*declarations*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1):

> A *declaration* introduces an entity into a program and includes an identifier (§3.8) that can be used in a name to refer to this entity. The identifier is constrained to be a type identifier when the entity being introduced is a class, interface, or type parameter.

`public static void main` is the beginning of a method declaration, but needs a parameter list and a method body to be complete.